# Survey Monkey API Query Parameters not working on Excel VBA

Tags: json, vba, excel, surveymonkey

I have a wrapper function that calls Survey Monkey methods on Excel VBA:

```
Function SM_Method(https As String, method As String, query As Variant) As String
    Dim objSM As Object
    Set objSM = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

    With objSM
        .Open https, charSMAPI & method & "?api_key=" & charAPIKey
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & charToken
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .Send query
        SM_Method = .responseText
    End With
End Function
```

I call this function as below which specifies the API query to print out certain fields:

```
Dim Request As Variant
Request = "{""fields"":[""per_page""]" & "}"
MsgBox (SM_Method("GET", "/surveys", Request))
```

But the above message box also prints out other fields such as "total", "data", "page", "links" etc...

I would love to get the query parameters working and was wondering what was wrong with my code above.  Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the request you're trying to do:

```
/v3/surveys?api_key=<key>&fields=per_page
```

And expecting the fields returned to only be per_page (no data, or anything else)?

I don't think that'll work, I think the `fields` url parameter only works for a specific resource, not a resource list.

So if you wanted to filter out a specific survey, this would work:

```
/v3/surveys/<survey_id>?api_key=<key>&fields=title
```

But not for a resource list, it'll always return the total amount of items available, which page you're currently on, how many items per page, the links for pagination, and all the resource items under `data`.

EDIT: Explaining how to get survey responses

The docs for fetching survey responses are [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses). What you'd want to do based on your comment is:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<id>/responses?api_key=<key>&email=<email>&start_created_at=<begin_range>&end_created_at=<end_range>
```

This will get you all the responses (by ID) for a respondent with the provided email, and within the date range specified by  and .

You can then fetch all the details of that response (every answer for every page) here:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<id>/responses/<response_id>?api_key=<key>
```

Given that you are using an email collector (that's how you have their email) and there should really only be one response ID returned in the list for that survey, unless they answered the survey more than once. If that's the case then you can do

```
GET /v3/surveys/<id>/responses/bulk?api_key=<key>&email=<email>&start_created_at=<begin_range>&end_created_at=<end_range>
```

Only, which with one request you can get all the responses including the answers for that given email in one request.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366206/accessing-surveymonkey-api-from-vba) **bold** somehow suggests

Comment: Ah that link is for V2 of the API, which works a bit differently. In that case, _only_ the fields specified in `fields` paramater show up. In V3 of the API, `fields` filters out everything but the ones specified, if you don't include it you get everything. You don't need to use that URL parameter in V3, I would just ignore it.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that I tried doing something like: Dim vRequestBody As String and assign vRequestBody = "{""survey_id:""86003167"",""fields"":[""title""]" & "}" and pass this input as part of the send method in the VBA function defined above.  Did not have much luck in subsetting the title only.  Seems like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366206/accessing-surveymonkey-api-from-vba) suggests that this would be the right way to approach but doesn't seem to work well with me... Thanks a lot for you help again!

Comment: I think what I would like to eventually achieve is to retrieve survey responses for a specific user(potentially identified by email) and/or for a specific time period.  Also, if the responses are across multiple pages, I'd like to access other pages a well by querying with the API.  It's kindda difficult to get that query condition to get working haha

Comment: @NeilCho I edited the answer, hopefully that helps you out a bit with what you're trying to do

Comment: Ah! This works great. It seems like all the queries can be done on the http statements.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have code like
vRequestBody = "{""survey_id"":" & Quoted(sSurveyID) _
            & ", ""fields"":[""collector_id"", ""url"", ""open"", ""type"", ""name"", ""date_created"", ""date_modified""]" _
            & "}"

or

vRequestBody = "{"_
            & JKeyValue("fields", Array("title", "date_created", "date_modified", "num_responses", _
            "language_id", "question_count", "preview_url", "analysis_url")) & "}"

Where JKeyValue uses the json class
https://code.google.com/archive/p/vba-json/

Function Quoted(var As Variant) As String
Quoted = Chr(34) & Replace(var, Chr(34), "''") & Chr(34) ' "str" with embedded double quotes replaced by pairs of single quotes
End Function

Function JKeyValue(sKey As String, vValues As Variant) As String
Dim jLib As New ClsJSONLib
JKeyValue = jLib.toString(sKey) & ":" & jLib.toString(vValues)
Set jLib = Nothing
End Function